# Mouse dragged without being pressed?

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx, javafx-2, mouseevent, javafx-8

I have this simple method to make a node draggable:

```
private void setNodeDraggable(final Node node) {
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        private Point2D dragAnchor;
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            EventType<? extends MouseEvent> type = event.getEventType();

            if (type == MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                dragAnchor = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            } else if (type == MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                try {
                    stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - dragAnchor.getX());
                    stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - dragAnchor.getY());
                } catch (Exception e) { ///catch all to track the occasional exception
                    LOG.error("in setNodeDraggable: {},{},{}", stage, event, dragAnchor);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    node.setOnMouseDragged(dragHandler);
    node.setOnMousePressed(dragHandler);
}
```

However an exception is thrown from time to time in the try block and the log shows that `dragAnchor` is null.

As far as I can see, the only explanation is that `MOUSE_DRAGGED` has been detected without a corresponding prior `MOUSE_PRESSED` event.

How is that possible? Is there anything I should change?

Comment: Tested your code on win8 with JavaFX 2.2.45. No exception. You should also specify your environment and version of JavaFX.

Comment: @UlukBiy Thanks for trying. I only get the exception ocassionally, not everytime - I run it with Java 8 b119 on Win7 x64.

Comment: I tried this on both JavaFX 2.2.45 and Java 8 b123, and couldn't generate the exception either. I tried initiating full drag on another component to see if that made any difference. Perhaps see if you can create a complete (but short) example which shows the problem. Maybe also try creating an ObjectProperty<Point2D> as your dragAnchor; then you can create different handlers for mousePressed and mouseDragged, but also register a listener with the dragAnchor to see when it changes.

Comment: @James_D I found the exception in a log file but it is very rare and I can't reproduce it systematically - I can just see in the log that it does happen... I'll try again. Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach. I suggest that when you are writing JavaFX programs, you cling more to JavaFX library. Forget old standards. I know this seems radical, but the JavaFX library comes with everything you need to develop your rich applications.

As I told you, about your problem I can offer you another approach. I do not know if it will be to your liking, but it is a very functional approach. My approach is to create two classes. One will serve as a utility class, and make the logical movement of the nodes, and the other will be your main class. Let's first look at the main class. In the main class we can find a method that makes any Node movable. We utilize the addition of two events on the node we want to become movable. Take a look:

```
protected void makeMovable(final Node node)
{
    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            // Just move node if the mouse button is the left button.
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)
            {
                NodeUtil.pressNode(node , e);
            }               
        }
    });

    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            // Just move node if the mouse button is the left button.
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)
            {
                NodeUtil.moveNode(node , e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In this code, as you can see, it just add handlers for certain types of events for the node argument on makeMovable method. The logic for the real movement of Node objects can be found within the NodeUtil class:

```
public final class NodeUtil 
{
    private static double dist_x = 0;
    private static double dist_y = 0;

    private NodeUtil(){}

    public static void pressNode(final Node node , final MouseEvent e)
    {
        dist_x = e.getSceneX() - node.getLayoutX();
        dist_y = e.getSceneY() - node.getLayoutY();
    }

    public static void moveNode(final Node node , final MouseEvent e)
    {
        node.setLayoutX( e.getSceneX() - dist_x );
        node.setLayoutY( e.getSceneY() - dist_y );
    }
}
```

That's basically it. All you must do now is to use these codes in your application. If you still have questions about some logic on the code, or encounter problems, please add a comment and I will help you.

I hope this works for you. Good luck in your projects. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but to be honest I don't see how it differs from my approach: you have refactored the pressNode/moveNode methods in a separate class but the logic seems similar to me.

Comment: It is difficult to point out the problem when we and other users have no access to your source code. Many users even commented that they did not get exceptions when running your application. If the code that introduced you end up showing you some exception, I can only conclude that you should update the JDK you are using.